# How to align author names?

Tags: vertical-alignment

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{A Paper}

\author{\begin{tabular}{l@{\ }l}

  Advisor: "Name of Advisor"

  Candidate: "My Name"

\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}


\maketitle


Given in this paper ...

\end{document}
```

My question is how to make the two colons right after "Advisor" and "Candidate" be on the same line?

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: `\maketitle` is missing  and what do you mean by the `same line`?  Aligned,but in different rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether this meant at all.

Please note, that journals have their own guidelines for typesetting/alignment of the names of authors.

The `@{\ }` is not useful at all, the first column is requested to be right justified, so use a `r` column specifier.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{A Paper}

\author{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
  Advisor:  &  ``Name of Advisor'' \tabularnewline
  Candidate: & ``Name of Candidate''
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle





Given in this paper ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. But I found that this creates a space before the colon. It seems that I have not specified my question clear enough. Please see my revision and thank you!

Comment: I was trying to make my question more general.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks again (anyway ;-))